# DXHTML Sheduler: multiple timelines on same page

Tags: javascript, timeline, dhtmlx-scheduler

I need to display a weekly shedule timeline, detailed by days, persons and their work hours. Please see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIt05.png) for example.

What I already tried:

Approach 1) display a timeline for one day ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheWar/pv6u0y7c/)), but I can't duplicate it for several days. [Result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK9Hf.png)

```
    scheduler.createTimelineView({
    name: "timeline",
    x_unit: "hour",
    x_date: "%H",
    days:7,
    x_step: 1,
    x_size: 12,
    x_start: 9,
    y_unit: scheduler.serverList("sections"),
    y_property: "section_id",
    render:"days", 
    });
```

Approach 2) display timeline for multiple days, hours and persons ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheWar/6xktdahj/)), but I can't swap rows and columns. [Result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN7Qt.png)

```
    scheduler.createUnitsView({
        name:"week_unit",
        property:"section_id",
        list:sections,
        days:7
    });
```

**How can I either display multiple days (approach1) or swap columns/rows (approach 2)?**

Answer (score 0):

Please read in the [article](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/multiple_per_page.html) how to create multiple instances of dhtmlxScheduler, i.e. multiple timelines on the same page.

Regarding the scale configuring - you can add the second scale with time - [example](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/06_timeline/07_second_scale.html).

Also I suggest you to check [all samples](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/06_timeline/) with the Timeline view and the [article](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html) that describes possibilities of the view, that will be helpful while you are working with Timeline.